# Is the next claim about automorphism group ${\rm \mathit Aut} _\mathbb{Q} (\mathbb{C})$ correct?

Tags: group-theory, field-theory, galois-theory

Let $G={\rm \mathit Aut} _\mathbb{Q} (\mathbb{C})$ be the automorphism group.

$K \subset \mathbb{C}$ is defined as $K =\ \bigr\{ \alpha \in \mathbb{C} \  |\  \sigma(\alpha) = \alpha \ ( \forall \sigma \in G)\bigl\}$ .

Then $K= \mathbb{Q} \ $ is true??

Comment: What sort of automorphisms do you mean? As a vector space or as an algebra?

Comment: automorphism as field.

Comment: and $\forall \sigma \in G \ ,\ \sigma | _\mathbb{Q} = {id}_{\mathbb{Q}} $

Comment: That last part follows from being an automorphism of fields.

Comment: I don't understand $K \subset \mathbb{Q}$.  Please prove it.

Comment: I meant the last part you wrote in the comments.